# Local SSL with Ruby / Puma

Tags: ruby, ssl, https, sinatra, puma

I'm running a local puma server and I can't get resources to load under SSL.

I have a local signed cert.

I'm trying to run the server with the following config:

```
puma -b 'ssl://127.0.0.1:9292?key=/path/to/certs/localhost.unecrypted.key&cert=/path/to/certs/localhost.crt'
```

Now, when I visit `https://localhost:9292` or `https://127.0.0.1:9292`,  the browser just spins and there isn't a response from the server. No resources are returned. Twice it has shown me the HTML title tag, but almost always I get nothing.

Any idea? Other ideas? Really need to run a https version of this app locally and I can't figure out how to do it.

Edit: The inital request is logged, but there is no response:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Sep/2013 11:29:15] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1265 0.0397
```

Sometimes I will get this error:

```
013-09-04 11:30:20 -0400: Read error: #<Errno::EPIPE: Broken pipe>
/Users/wesbos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@sinatra/gems/puma-2.3.2/lib/puma/minissl.rb:56:in `write'
/Users/wesbos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@sinatra/gems/puma-2.3.2/lib/puma/minissl.rb:56:in `write'
/Users/wesbos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@sinatra/gems/puma-2.3.2/lib/puma/server.rb:635:in `fast_write'
/Users/wesbos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@sinatra/gems/puma-2.3.2/lib/puma/server.rb:484:in `handle_request'
/Users/wesbos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@sinatra/gems/puma-2.3.2/lib/puma/server.rb:248:in `process_client'
/Users/wesbos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@sinatra/gems/puma-2.3.2/lib/puma/server.rb:147:in `block in run'
/Users/wesbos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@sinatra/gems/puma-2.3.2/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:92:in `call'
/Users/wesbos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@sinatra/gems/puma-2.3.2/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:92:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out Puma has problems with SSL right now:

https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/350

Reverting to version 1.6.3 fixed it for me